# Take value of time as input from the user and adjust a delay equal to that time in multiple threads

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, sleep

I have 20 threads running in my program. Each thread has a Sleep(t) of time 't'.

I have a single window on which there is an edit box. I want my user to enter a value in that edit box and then I want all my threads to adjust their Sleep() according to that input value.

If all the threads directly read the variable in which the user has input the value, keep a copy of that variable and adjust their Sleep() time according to that value, would there be synchronization issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only one thread writes the value, 20 others only read it. Sync issues could be when several threads write value.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization becomes complicated when sleep() is used. Its not preferable to synchronize 20 threads with sleep.U wont face any prob when only read is concerned.